# Rails date input format

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, date

I'm trying to make input form for some date field (choosing date with jquery-ui)
I'm using rails 4, it always consider this `dd/mm/yyyy`,  meanwhile my input is `mm/dd/yyyy`
I did changed in config/locales/en.yml as follow:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  date:
    order:
      - month
      - day
      - year
```

but the result still the same.

my debugging

```
(rdb:1) @booking
Booking id: nil, **booking_date: nil**, guest_name: "as",

(rdb:1) booking_params
{"booking_date"=>"04/24/2014", "guest_name"=>"as",
```

probably this is beginner question, thanks for help

for reference this is my controller

```
def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
    debugger
    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "data saved succesfully"
      redirect_to bookings_path 
    else
      render 'bookings/booking_form'
    end
  end
```

this is view

```
<%= form_for @booking do |f| %>
    <%= render 'common/form_errors', object: @booking %>
  <p>
     <%= f.label :booking_date, "Booking Date" %>
     <%= f.text_field :booking_date, :class => :datepicker  %>
  </p>
```

Comment: why don't you change the format of datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `date format` for `datepicker` while selecting the value itself:

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/d6mSA/187/

```
<script>
    //make sure you have referenced `JQuery` and `JQuery-UI` resources before the code below
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })
    });

</script>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, it works,  I'm using your solution probably for temporary I'm still searching how rails can accept my default date format mm-dd-yy since my end user directly using this format

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by declaring a method, e.g., `update_date` with params as argument and call this in your action before performing save or update, look at this example

```
def update_date(params)
  date_string = params[:booking][:booking_date].split("-")
  params[:booking][:booking_date] = date_string[1]+"-"+date_string[0]+"-"+date_string[2]  
end
```

You can also put it in `before_filter`, so its upto you how you want to implement, I've given you the logic.